# Issue with openlayer-3's official measure example

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

There is a tiny issue with the official Measure example. When drawing a polygon, if the last vertex (the one which should close/end the polygon) overlaps the measure tooltip, then the polygon cannot be closed/ended.

It seems the click event is happening on the tooltip's div and not in the map.

The example is on:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

Answer (score 2):

You may solve this using `stopEvent: false` when declaring the `measureTooltip`.

According to the [api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html), event propagation to the map viewport should not be stopped when false. Default is true so set it to false.

```
measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    stopEvent: false,
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
```

And a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/d1skmgdt/)